# What is "gons" in Olympus Finance?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, defi

In Olympus Finance, there is a concept called "gons", which is the internal representation of [sOHM](https://github.com/OlympusDAO/olympus-contracts/blob/Version-2/contracts/sOlympusERC20.sol) balance. What exactly is "gons" and what is the purpose of using it instead of storing the actual balances?

Comment: While this is tangential to the Ethereum blockchain, I think most users of this forum will not be able to answer your question. I suggest reaching out to the Olympus Finance community directly, e.g. in their Discord server.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the recommendation. I went to its server and found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I [found](https://discord.com/channels/838651642190495804/846083782025281577/905383553892745226) in Olympus DAO's Discord server, rebase happens every epoch and the balance of every staker increases by x amount depending on the APY. It would be too expensive to directly transfer tokens to every staker due to the gas fees. Instead, the variable `_gonsPerFragment` is adjusted so that every staker's balance is automatically scaled in the function `balanceOf`. `_gonsPerFragment` decreases every rebase as a result of an increasing `_totalSupply`, which means each staker's balance increases as `_gonsPerFragment` is a denominator in the function.